# What is that annotation mean: Make this the iterator's operator*() after the 4.0 release

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, llvm

Code is in LLVM 7.0.0, here:
llvm/include/llvm/IR/GetElementPtrTypeIterator.h

```
    // FIXME: Make this the iterator's operator*() after the 4.0 release.
    // operator*() had a different meaning in earlier releases, so we're
    // temporarily not giving this iterator an operator*() to avoid a subtle
    // semantics break.
    Type *getIndexedType() const {
      if (auto *T = CurTy.dyn_cast<Type *>())
        return T;
      return CurTy.get<StructType *>()->getTypeAtIndex(getOperand());
    }
```

I am working on LLVM 7.0.0, I am confused about what is that message want let me do, like there is anything I need to add or fix,I have find everything on the Internet and no solution.
Any suggestions will be be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you really wanna fix someone else's code? If it works, just leave it. If you wanted to contribute to the project, make an issue on their github repo. From personal experience, I don't even think the dev who wrote this FIXME comment even knows what is it about without spending time investigating by now.

Comment: A likely option is that the design decision to change this in 4.0 was dropped, and the comment is now incorrect.

Comment: `git blame` quickly finds the commit that introduces the lines. The commit comment explains, and also links to [the discussion during code review](https://reviews.llvm.org/D26594). Git really is a marvellous tool.

Comment: @Caleth That is utterly unlikely.  The likely case is someone wrote the FIXME and never got around to even thinking about it after the 4.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the comment: The quoted function should be `operator*()`, but because the class already had a function named `operator*()`, the new function was named `getIndexedType()` instead. The other function existed because `operator*()` originally had a different meaning. The intention was to remove the previous `operator*()` after 4.0 release, and rename `getIndexedType()` to `operator*()`.

Based on "we're temporarily not giving this iterator an `operator*()`", I think the previous `operator*()` has already been removed, but I didn't check the code to be sure.

As changing the behavior of a function would be a breaking change, it was left for the next major version. The current version is 7.0, which is after 4.0, but perhaps the developers have not wanted to introduce such a change yet. You should ask what the consensus among the developers is before making the change.

Comment: "not wanted" laugh out loud.  No, I am 100% sure that nobody remembered to do it; it wasn't even considered.